# Windows 8 Installation Issue

Tags: windows, virtualbox, windows-8-preview

I recently installed Windows 8 consumer preview using Oracle Virtual Box. I have done the necessary configurations and this error got displayed as I start-up.

Your PC needs to restart. 
Please hold down the power button. 
Error code: 0x0000005D 
Parameters: 
0x03062502
...

Any idea of what's causing this problem & What should I do to resolve it?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wes8/thread/996a74f7-1a71-4b21-a408-6e951d75d584

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved the same issue. Take a look at [this post](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/26800/windows-8-on-virtualbox-and-vmware-your-pc-needs-to-restart-fix/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20Tech-RecipesMain%20%28Tech-Recipes%20Main%29). The idea is that you need to turn on the BIOS option (on your host machine) to prevent execution in non-executable memory segments.

Comment: And what if you **have** enabled the Memory Protection in BIOS, and you **still** get this error?!?!?

Comment: Is the error you see exactly the same? I think the solution in the post applies to the **customer preview" version of Windows 8, which I installed a few months back. Are you using the same version?

Comment: Ah - I am using the Win8 RTM Trial version - and I just couldn't get it to work in Oracle VirtualBox, had to use VMWare Workstation 9 instead. Works like a charm there! THanks.