# "Your PC Needs To Restart" error on VMware Player 5 when installing Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, vmware-player

I'm trying to install the latest Windows 8 preview on VMware Player 5, after trying build 8200 for a while.

Immediately after booting, it gives me the following error:

> Your PC Needs To Restart.
>   Please hold down the power button.
>   Error Code: 0x0000005D

I have seen [some other questions](https://superuser.com/questions/433279/windows-8-installation-issue) that recommend turning on a BIOS setting, but the old motherboard I am using does not appear to have such a setting.

Are there any workarounds?

**EDIT**
My motherboard is an ASUS P5LD2 with an intel core 2 duo.
I am now going through all the options in the bios that sound remotely like *No-Execute Memory Protection*, *data execution protection* or *no-execute protection*, but there's definitely no option that mentions protection.

Comment: PAE and NX support are in the [system requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh975398.aspx) of Windows 8. If you have an early XP-era CPU it probably doesn't have it, but most recent ones have it. It could be under a variety of names like data execution protection and no-execute protection. To help us help you, could you also list the model of your cpu and motherboard.

Comment: test another **Solution** to solve above error : download & Install Virtual Box 4.1 on your machine & deploy Windows 8 Developer Preview Virtual Machine on top of it.  
 http://www.mytricks.in/2011/09/guide-install-windows-8-developer.html

Comment: What processor & RAM do you have?

Comment: I just wrote a simple helper to check for those features in a processor, shows a line indicating if it supports each one or not: http://goo.gl/h54Hi The error code you receive indicates that your processor doesn't meet those requirements.

Comment: Actually... you're using a Core2 processor, I believe all those were 64-bit capable and all 64-bit capable processors support NX. Intel called that feature eXecute Disable, look for that under advanced CPU settings in your BIOS configuration utility.

Answer (score 0):

From [Unable to install Windows 8 - Error Code 0x0000005D](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/27098-unable-to-install-windows-8-error-code-0x0000005d):

> Unlike Windows Vista and 7, Windows 8 (as from build 8400) is not
>   compatible with all models of the Pentium 4 processor.
>
> This is due to the fact that Windows 8 requires a processor compatible
>   with the following functions: SSE2, PAE and NX bit. All Pentium 4 are
>   compatible with SSE2 and EAP: the problem may come from the NX bit.
>
> - First, make sure your Pentium 4 model supports the NX bit: for    sockets 423 or 478 processors, then it won't work (in most cases).
> - For sockets 775 processors, it can be compatible. If the CPU supports    NX-bit, you can install Windows 8 32-bit or 64-bit (it
>     depends on the    models!).
> - Also make sure that NX bit is not disabled in the BIOS (if present).

Here's a how-to guide to help you [fix this specific problem](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/26800/windows-8-on-virtualbox-and-vmware-your-pc-needs-to-restart-fix/) .

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Hyder! Please do not simply copy and paste content from other sites without linking to them and properly placing it in blockquotes. I've added the link and the quote for you, but please remember this in the future.